# Pyramid: permissions by user and organizations

Tags: authorization, pyramid, roles

I'm developing an application which has administrators associated with different organizations, and these organizations are put together into a hierarchy.

I need to implement roles associated with the administrator according to the organization: the same administrator would have read-only permission in one branch of the tree and read and write permissions in another branch. An administrator user may have read permission over Sales OU and write over Personal OU.

How do I integrate this into an Authorization component?

For example:

Callback get_roles returns (mongodb):

```
"roles" : [ 
  { "562f7b14e488e3665c4700bc" : [ "read" ] },
  { "572200d1e488e30757e739d5" : [ "write" ] } 
]
```

- 562f7b14e488e3665c4700bc: Sales OU identifier
- 572200d1e488e30757e739d5: Personal OU identifier

Comment: So, what is exactly your question? What have you researched/attempted? What is the issue that you are currently facing?

Comment: A administrator can have permission read over Sales OU and write over Personal OU. How do I integrate this into Authorization mechanism ?

Comment: Callback get_roles returns (mongodb)

 "roles" : [
  {
   "562f7b14e488e3665c4700bc" : [
    "read"
   ]
  },
  {
   "572200d1e488e30757e739d5" : [
    "write"
   ]
  }
 ]

562f7b14e488e3665c4700bc: Sales OU identifier 
572200d1e488e30757e739d5: Personal OU identifier

Comment: Please include those **in the question** instead of adding it in the comment

Comment: Looks like you need to use ABAC in addition to RBAC. ABAC will let you express hierarchical access control as well as relationships.